# Edit rows where column contains strings+ empty spaces

Tags: php, mysql

I have some rows ( > 50.000) in my database which contains columns with  strings + '\n'. I mean the records looks like this:

```
  abcd\n or \nabcd
```

Because of that sometimes my application does not work correctly. My question is: How could i update this rows with the correct value and eliminate '\n' spaces besides going to every row and update it manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table set somecolumn = replace(somecolumn, '\n', '')
```

Comment: thank you ! i was lazy i should have looked over mysql manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
update mytable SET title = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
UPDATE table SET column=REPLACE(column,'\\n','') WHERE column LIKE '%\\n' OR column LIKE '\\n%'
```

If you don't know where the new line is, simply:

```
UPDATE table SET column=REPLACE(column,'\\n','')
```

Comment: Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences